# Bootstrap navigation not working on subpages

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This website I've been working on has me banging my head against the wall already. I've looked all over StackOverflow and all over the web, but no one seems to have the same problem as I do, so I'm thinking it might be a simple fix, but just in case... here's my problem:

My website has been built using Bootstrap so far, and it has a nav bar at the top of the screen, two of the link on the navigation have dropdown menus. These dropdown menus only reveal themselves when I'm not accessing them from a subpage (or a page listed on one of those dropdown menus). The code I'm using for every page for the nav bar is the exact same (except for file paths of course), here it is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">Southeast Helping Hands</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../community_resources.html">Community Resources</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Events <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="../events.html">Events Calendar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Community Christmas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Food Handouts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#more-info" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">More Info <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>
```

I've isolated it to this code and I don't believe my CSS has anything to do with it. For that matter, whenever the screen gets smaller than a certain width, the navigation links are replaced with a hamburger menu button that reveals the menu when clicked, this button does not work either on subpages.

*To clarify, the navigation links work fine, but the drop down menus won't reveal once I click on them.*

Comment: you probably don't have the necessary Bootstrap javascript files linked at the bottom of your page. What version of BS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything to go by in this sample code. I would most likely suspect that your resources aren't linked properly on your subpages. If they're not in the same directory as your main page and you copy pasted the html link tags, then they might not point the same way. Unless you include a screenshot of your file structure and include the html where you reference your resources, I don't know that enough information is present to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should clarify, the dropdown navigation doesn't reveal once I click it, nothing happens. The links are all perfectly connected, just the dropdown navigation doesn't show.

Comment: This piece of code makes me think that your problem is that you haven't rewritten your paths to account for the location of your secondary pages in your file structure: <li><a href="../events.html">Events Calendar</a></li>

Comment: If that piece of code is valid in your landing page, then it can't be valid on your events.html page because based on the code, the two pages aren't in the same directory.

Comment: For reference, whenever you write a filepath, the root directory for the address you're referencing is considered the directory in which the file resides. Two files can't use the same filepath the access the same resource if they aren't in the same directory.

Comment: Another thing you didn't specify is whether you were using a CDN for bootstrap or a local file. If you're using a local file, then you probably haven't properly referenced your bootstrap.js.

Comment: It just so happens that my bootstrap.js was not properly referenced, I figured it might be some stupid mistake, it's working now!